# C# Expand Flat List<T> to Dictionary<T,ICollection<int>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I've got a `List<MyClass>`:

```
public int MyClass
{
   public int One { get; set; }
   public int Two { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the data can (and does) look like this:

> One: 1, Two: 9
>
> One: 2, Two: 9
>
> One: 1, Two: 8
>
> One: 3, Two: 7

See how "One" appears twice? I want to project this flat sequence into a grouped `Dictionary<int,ICollection<int>>`:

> KeyValuePairOne: { Key: 1, Value: { 9, 8 }}
>
> KeyValuePairTwo: { Key: 2, Value: { 9 }}
>
> KeyValuePairThree: { Key: 3, Value: { 7 }}

I'm guessing i need to do a combination of `.GroupBy` and `.ToDictionary`?

Comment: You're in a good direction. What have you tried?

Comment: yep that exactly what I would do

Comment: @Yorye - i've tried an ugly loop, and i knew it wasn't the right way to do it, but didn't know how to approach using `.GroupBy` and `.ToDictionary` together here,  so i came onto stack and asked for help. :)

Comment: @RPM1984 You should've read about those extension methods and look for some examples. Learning from the internet without relying on responses is a powerful skill.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - agreed. I know how to use each individually, just had a brain freeze and couldn't for the life of me figure out how to combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();

var dictionary = list.GroupBy(x => x.One)
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());
```

Comment: correct, but its actually `x => x.Select(y => y.Two).ToArray()` in the `.ToDictionary>`, because i want to end up with a `Dictionary<int,ICollection<int>>` not `Dictionary<int,ICollection<MyClass>>`

Comment: My bad. But as long as you have the solution, I'm happy.

Answer (score 4):

This is what [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) extension method is for.  Where ToDictionary will throw if the key shows up twice, ToLookup instead is fine with it and does what you're looking for.

Comment: ToLookup is pretty much like doing GroupBy, which alone doesn't suffice as solution to the question (making Dictionary out of it)

Comment: @YoryeNathan it's more concise than GroupBy: one phrase instead of two.  Plus, your answer *is exactly that* -- to do a GroupBy -- so evidently you think that it does suffice (or at least is the best solution).

Comment: GroupBy is correct, but with addition of ToDictionary. ToLookup with addition of ToDictionary also works. Which, by the way, isn't shorter in any way. All I'm saying is that you will still need ToDictionary since the OP wanted a dictionary.

Comment: @YoryeNathan gotcha- fair enough.

Comment: I take back the "not shorter" argument, as I just now understood the OP wanted `Dictionary<int, ICollection<int>>` and not `Dictionary<int, MyClass>`, so passing a value selector to the LoopUp will indeed be more concise. However, you are adding a few calls and delegates by wrapping it by an unnecessary Lookup.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how you'd do it:

```
Dictionary<int, List<MyClass>> result =
    items.GroupBy(x => x.One).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: Why not use var? Also, .ToArray() will also make ICollection, and is more efficient. You should make a List only if you intend on using Add/Remove on the ICollection.

Comment: This is a little off topic, but why use var? Isn't the concrete definition more readable and concise?

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Three points here. One: A `List` is also an `ICollection`; what your code actually creates is a `Dictionary<int, MyClass[]>`. Two: If you *didn't* use `var`, you'd have noticed that. Three: I tested 10,000 iterations of both. List: 0.9582951 seconds. Array: 0.957012 seconds. I don't think it matters.

Comment: Update: That's in Debug mode. In Release mode, it's List: 1.13 seconds, Array: 1.56 seconds. So I'd rather use `List`.

Comment: @minitech Yes, my code would do that, but you can see OP's comment on my answer. I did notice that was what my code was doing, I just wasn't paying attention to the actual needed result in the question. Using var makes the code much more readable in my opinion, and finally - when testing for array vs list you should also test accessing elements, and I'd prefer if you did that in a manner when it took at least 5 seconds for one of them, for better comparison. It is known that array's are best for accessing elements.